# Pose Mode Becomes Laggy When Attaching Weapon "Bone" to Arm Rig

Tags: rigging

[Twirling Donut Blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eo5k_4Ba7H0AkV5_CrNZjlt0YI8yNcBd/view?usp=sharing)

Hey Folks!

I've recently been progressing through my Blender journey and I'd like to create an animation using some assets I've built.

I've created an Arm, with an Armature inside of it, and I've imported a Sword I made, which I also placed a Bone Into.  I then made that bone linked to the Arm rig, and linked the sword bone to the middle index bone.

However, when I do that, I can no longer move my objects around (they also don't appear linked to each other).  Basically it becomes very laggy (about 5 seconds per mouse move).  I'm on a pretty beefy machine (3080, top tier CPU, etc...), so I suspect it's something I'm doing wrong.  Deleting the linkage returns the entire process back to normal, with zero lag.

I appreciate any advice or suggestions you might have!

Comment: Screenshots or gifs?

Comment: My immediate suspicion is that the sword has a certified blizzard of vertices, so the deform takes a long time. How many verts does the sword have?

Comment: Ah... so, yes, I have an alarming number of vertices.  It was my first sword :)  Okay, so, I'll go back the the drawing board before trying this animation and attempt to build a low poly sword!

Comment: you can also try Limited Dissolve, or Decimate, or Un-Subdivide on your existing model.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TheLabCat for the appropriate answer, the issue was that my sword had a certified blizzard of vertices!  Reducing the poly count on the sword will likely fix the issue.  I reduced my sword model from... (don't judge) 6 million vertices to about 3,000 and things seem to be running smoothly.